# why app.listen should be at the end after all the requests? also why is it necessary?

Tags: node.js, express

```
const app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello there");
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on ${PORT}`));
```

Here why app.listen is at the end ? shouldn't it be placed before app.get so that its listening at port 5000 for requests  ?

Answer (score 13):

> Here why `app.listen()` is at the end ?

See below, but mostly as a convention to use a logical and safe order of initialization where you configure the server first before starting it and exposing it to incoming connections.

> shouldn't it be placed before `app.get()` so that its listening at port 5000 for requests

No, `app.get()` registers route handlers.  "registers" in this case means that it adds the route to an internal list so then, when some future incoming request arrives, Express can look through the list to see which route handlers match the requested path.  The `app` object needs to be created before registering a route handler on it, but it doesn't matter at all whether the server has already been started or not.

Remember, all that is happening with an `app.get()` is that you're adding a route definition to an internal list so it can then (at some time in the future) be compared to an incoming path to see if it matches.  It's not actually running any route handlers.  You can think of it logically as if you're registering an event listener.  Similarly all that does is add some data to a list so something may be called in the future.

So, we've shown that it doesn't really matter whether you've called `app.listen()` before or after you register your routes.  The routes get registered (for future use) either way.

It seems to somewhat be a common convention to configure the server and then start the server, but there is no reason it has to be done that way.

If you start your server and then configure the routes, it seems logically like there might be a window in time where the server is running, but all the routes aren't yet defined and that could create an odd time window where one might connect to the server expecting it to be functioning normal, but it isn't fully configured yet.  But, because of the single-threaded nature of Javascript, this likely wouldn't cause an issue.  If an incoming request arrives after you have started your server, but before you've configured all your routes that still won't cause a problem.  This is because, while your synchronous server initialization code runs, the incoming request will be inserted into the Javascript event queue and it won't be pulled out of the queue until whatever Javascript you were currently running is done. So, as long as you defined all your routes in this Javascript, they would be fully configured before the first request is actually processed.  This means all your routes will still be defined before that incoming request gets processed.  So, they will be in place in time.

So ... it seems that for most normal synchronous server initialization code, it doesn't really matter whether you do `app.listen()` before or after configuring your routes.  It is likely done last just as a logical convention that seems the appropriate order to do things (configure the server, then start the server).

I should mention one edge case.  If, for some reason, part of your server initialization involved making asynchronous calls (e.g. some `app.get()` was inside some asynchronous callback) and you were doing `app.listen()` before that callback fired, then you would have an open window of time where the server was running, but not properly configured yet.  This isn't the usual way a server is configured, but it still could be done.  So, in this case to avoid ever processing requests on a partially configured server, you would need to wait to call `app.listen()` until after all the asynchronous operations were done.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with jfriend00's explanation; it's a common point of confusion when starting with Node.js. When dealing with `app.listen()`, it's crucial to ensure that this statement follows all the initializations like `app.get()`, `app.put()`, `app.all()`, and so on. While both approaches might seem to work, this order is a best practice.

At its core, clients can't establish connections with a blank server. Understanding this concept is essential, so I recommend delving into why this order is recommended rather than just considering it a convention.

Hope this clarifies things for you!