# Heroku App Keeps Crashing Because Port is Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

This is the setup I have in my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const host = '0.0.0.0';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.listen(PORT, host, () => {
  console.log(`RABC Server is listening on port ${PORT}!`)
});

app.use(express.static('public'))
```

This is what I have in my Procfile:

```
web:nodemon server.js
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

This is what I get when I log the port:

The value of PORT is: undefined

In my package.json scripts I have:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js", 
    "build": "sanity build"
 }
```

I don't have a .env file and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to have one, and what to have in there.

When I run the 'heroku local web' and host locally everything works fine.

I have never deployed or hosted an app in my life this is my first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `server.js` to,

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`RABC Server is listening on port ${PORT}!`)
});
```

Move `app.listen` to the end,

> It's just a convention to use a logical and safe order of initialization where you configure the server first before starting it.

Refer: [why app.listen should be at the end after all the requests? also why is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835089/why-app-listen-should-be-at-the-end-after-all-the-requests-also-why-is-it-neces)

Also, update Procfile to

```
web:npm run start
```

Comment: Man thank you so much, this was killing me, you don't know how much this has helped me.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help! Cheers!