# Why we should write app.get("/", function (req, res){}) before app.listen(3000)?

Tags: node.js, express, server

I tried to listen to the port and then giving back the response to the browser and that too worked.
Then why we listen afterwards?

**eg:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It's usually more logical to define the event listeners before initiating the thing that would fire the events you listen to.

Comment: See if this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835089/why-app-listen-should-be-at-the-end-after-all-the-requests-also-why-is-it-neces) - but generally, it's a matter of readability and logical sequence and not something that the express framework force you to do.